# Is Instagram unable to block unauthorized use of their private API?

Tags: instagram-api

Instagram does not allow developers to post images through their public API but there are a lot of apps that support this feature like [6tag](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/6tag/9wzdncrfhvxc) on Windows Phone or Insta10 on BlackBerry. How do they keep Instagram from shutting their apps down? Do they use some kind of VPN?